# How to integrate Apache Ofbiz with Broadleaf commerce

Tags: ofbiz, broadleaf-commerce

I have developed broadleaf commerce custom module web application project, and now i want to integrate some functionality such payment system, management system and so on with Apache Ofbiz. Can anyone help me on this ?
Broadleaf Commmerce url : http://docs.broadleafcommerce.org
Apache Ofbiz url : http://ofbiz.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

It makes more sense to simply replace Ofbiz with Broadleaf if you want to go down that route. They are both pretty hefty ecommerce frameworks that serve the same purpose.

I would recommend instead integrating whatever payment modules and management system that you need into Broadleaf directly and drop Ofbiz.

Which integrations are you looking for with Broadleaf that you couldn't find?